# [react-native]TextInput didn't insert newline when pressed return key

Tags: android, react-native

Below is the code:

```
<TextInput multiline={true} style={{height:160}} onChangeText={(text) => this._changeBody(text)} value={this.state.body} blurOnSubmit={false} placeholder={ARTICLE_BODY_TIPS}/>
```

when I pressed the return key, it didn't insert the newline,os is android, and the RN version is 0.43.3

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/S1x65UOyb here's a working demo. Everything works fine for me.

Comment: your RN version is 0.43.3?it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I just saw an open issue about this. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12717 For now, the best solution is to downgrade back to an older version of RN. If its about working on a single client, just change your phone's keyboard to google keyboard. No issues with that, or the native one.

Comment: hm, it's a bug, thank you very much!

Comment: This bug depends also on software keyboard, no problem on stock, doesn't work on samsung phone

Answer (score 0):

Try it! It works in the middle of the line also!

```
<TextInput
              value={this.state.query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text, allowEditing: true })}

              selection = {this.state.selection}
              onSelectionChange={(event) => this.setState({ cursorPosition: event.nativeEvent.selection, selection: event.nativeEvent.selection, allowEditing: true })}
              onSubmitEditing={() => {
                const { query, cursorPosition } = this.state;
                let newText = query;
                const ar = newText.split('');
                ar.splice(cursorPosition.start, 0, '\n');
                newText = ar.join('');
                if (cursorPosition.start === query.length && query.endsWith('\n')) {
                  this.setState({ query: newText });
                } else if (this.state.allowEditing) {
                  this.setState({
                    query: newText,
                    selection: {
                      start: cursorPosition.start + 1,
                      end: cursorPosition.end + 1
                    },
                    allowEditing: !this.state.allowEditing
                  });
                }
              }}
              multiline = {true}
              numberOfLines = {10}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              editable={true}
            />
this.state = {
  query: '',
  cursorPosition: [0,0],
  selection: null,
  allowEditing: true
}
```